# How to manage versioning for changes that only affect some pieces of a package?

Tags: programming-languages, api-design, versioning, packages, package-managers

I'm designing a new language and the package-management system for it (something like NPM, Cargo, Pip, Gem, Cpan, Cabal, NuGet or the like).

I'm trying to decide what's a good way to handle the versioning of a package when only part of it is updated. I'm also curious to learn what's the best way to solve this problem with existing package managers.

#### Example of the problem

Let's suppose a package exports some types and functions that many other packages use:

```
# package: string 1.0

type String {
  length: Number,
  data: byte*
}

function from_NUL_terminated( data: byte[] ) -> String { ... }
function to_NUL_terminated( string: String ) -> byte[] { ... }
function from_repeated_char( length: Number, char: byte ) -> String { ... }
function get_UTF8_length( string: String ) -> Number { ... }
# ...
```

At some point, something in the "string" package needs to be changed. For instance a bug in `from_NUL_terminated()` gets fixed, or a new function `get_UTF16_length()` is added.

Because of this change, a new version of the "string" package is released: string 1.1.
This makes everything incompatible between the two versions: the language considers `String` from "string 1.0" a different type from `String` from "string 1.1". Even though the `String` type didn't change: only other stuff in that package did.

A consequence is that packages that depend on a different version of "string" cannot pass `String`s to each other. A little function that is only used internally by a few packages causes a major split in the ecosystem of the language.

Obviously this problem must be avoided. How?

#### Further thoughts about the problem

From the example above it sounds like only types need to be protected from this issue. That's practical in most cases, but it's not technically correct. Ideally functions that don't change shouldn't be re-released in the new version either.

It sounds like every *item* in a package should have its own versioning, rather than package itself: every type, every function, every piece of data or metada.

#### What's the solution?

How do existing languages and their package managers handle this situation?

And how could I handle it for my new language and its new package manager? Can the package manager fix this problem on its own for any language, or would it need support from the language to do things properly?

#### Addendum: a minimal example showing the problem in Node.js

I created a project in Rust where two different versions of the crate "mystr" are used by the "main" crate and the "printerlib" crate: https://github.com/BlueNebulaDev/rust-version-test . (a crate is a package in Rust terminology)

The "mystr" crate exposes a type `MyStr`. This type is defined identically in both version. "mystr 2.0.0" also exposes a function that wasn't available in the previous version: `mystr::from_slice()`.

The program can't compile, because the "main" package creates an `mystr(1.0.0)::MyStr` object and tries to pass it to a function that expects a `mystr(2.0.0)::MyStr` object. However `MyStr` never changes in the two versions: it's only other functions in the same crate that change.

I also created a Node.js project showing the same issue in that environment: https://github.com/BlueNebulaDev/node-version-test/ .

Comment: For versioning without declaring all version changes incompatible with each other, you may want to look at Semantic Versioning (https://semver.org/)

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: I don't believe that it completely fixes the problem. Let's say that the function `get_UTF8_length()` needs to be removed from the string package. That's an "incompatible API change", thus it requires a MAJOR version. Nevertheless, `String` was not touched.

Answer (score 3):

> the language considers String from "string 1.0" a different type from String from "string 1.1"

Well, you found a major flow in the language you're designing.

Types should be identified by their namespace. As soon as the namespace is kept unchanged between versions, a consumer would use `string.String` independently if the type is actually defined in version 1.0 or 6.5.0.814 of the library.

As for the package management systems, they [should be smart enough](https://medium.com/@imdongchen/how-does-npm-handle-conflicting-package-versions-44f90950cca5) when asked to install different versions of the same package. Usually, this is done by specifying not the hardcoded versions of the dependencies, but only the specific requirements. For instance, the dependency `x` may depend on package `z` version 3.0.2 or higher, whereas the dependency `y` may require package `z` version 3.4.*. The package management system understands then that it needs to install the version of `z` which is compatible with both requirements. Or, in other cases, requirements may be conflicting, and the package manager will halt and alert the user about the problem.

Comment: What makes you think that I know nothing about static linking and dynamic linking, other languages and package managers? I believe I already know about that. Yes, in most cases symbols inside an ELF or a PE are referred simply by their name (which might be a mangled variant of the actual identifier, depending on the language). But binary files don't contain information about types, they only contain data (e.g. strings), the compiled binary code of functions (text) etc. Type information, which is what I'm asking about is only stored in the package and doesn't have much to do with linking.

Comment: The compiler/interpreter of a language uses the information written in the package file and for many languages, the same *item* defined in two different packages (or different versions of the same package) are considered different. I'll upload on github an example of this using node.js and npm (where it doesn't matter, since javascript is duck typed, but you can still see that the types are different). I believe that many other languages behave the same way.

Comment: Otherwise, what happens in the following scenario? `String` changes from "string 1.0" to "string 1.1". Your package uses "string 1.1" and tries to pass a `String` to a function defined in a "package x". "package x" uses "string 1.0". If the compiler simply allowed you to pass your `String` 1.1, the program would break at runtime... How does a language fixes this potential problem?

Comment: Here I created the example project I promised above: https://github.com/BlueNebulaDev/node-version-test/ . It shows that in Node, something imported from `base 1.0.0` is different from something imported from `base 1.1.0` even though the "signature" is exactly identical. The same thing happens to, for example, Rust types.

Comment: *“What makes you think that I know nothing about static linking and dynamic linking, other languages and package managers?”*: oh, my apologies then. Reading your question, I had an impression that you weren't aware of all those things, because the sort of problems you describe in your question doesn't exist in many other languages.

Comment: *“something imported from base 1.0.0 is different from something imported from base 1.1.0 even though the "signature" is exactly identical”*: obviously, since you're using two different packages, not two versions of the same package. What is possibly misleading is that Node is perfectly happy pretending that those two packages have the same name—it would be clearer if it would complain during the second `require`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In node.js, as well as in Rust, *items* coming from a package are different from the items coming from a different version of the same package. Imagine the following scenario in Rust (or Node, or most other languages with packages/modules: i.e. excluding C and C++): your package includes "string 1.0", instantiates a `String` and tries to pass it to "packageB", who includes "string 1.1". The compiler doesn't let you do that, because the `String` you're trying to pass is different to the one that is expected, even though the type signature is identical.

Comment: Well, this is not a situation you'll find in production. Imagine that you import two packages, both depending on `lodash`. Either `npm` will figure out how to install *one* (and only one) version of `lodash` which makes happy both packages, or it will plainly tell that the requirements cannot be met. What you showed in your GitHub example is not a practical problem, but rather a theoretical thing where you tricked Node into calling two different packages by the same name.

Comment: I prepared a more realist example in Rust, here: https://github.com/BlueNebulaDev/rust-version-test
`main` uses `mystr-2.0.0` and `printerlib`. `printerlib` uses `mystr-1.0.0`. Main instantiates a `mystr::MyStr` and tries to pass it to `printerlib::print`. It fails because the two crates expect a different verison of the `mystr` crate. The type `mystr::MyStr` didn't change from version 1.0.0 to version 2.0.0: the only thing that changed is that a new function was added. Does this look like a realistic example?

Comment: @BlueNebula That's still not a very realistic example because if the only change to MyStr was the addition of a function then it should have been a semver-minor update, not semver-major.

Comment: @curiousdannii: what if a function or a different struct in the mystr package was modified or removed? That would cause a major change of the whole package according to semver, in spite of `MyStr` not changing.

Comment: @BlueNebula Yes, and then the consumers of the library need to figure out what they'll do. It's a good thing if the package manager won't pretend it can ignore semver-major updates like they didn't exist.